# Xamarin Forms: duplicated Toolbar in Master Detail Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbar, master-detail

I am currently working on a project in Xamarin Forms and Andoird (iOS support will be added later).
The app has a `MasterDetailPage` as `HomePage` and a `ToolBar`, which works fine.

In one of my `DetailPages` there is an `ToolbarItem` that links to another Page:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new ShoppingCartPage()));
```

When I am at the `ShoppingCartPage` I got a duplicated Toolbar and I don't know why (see [ScreenshotPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qqH2.png))

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to show just one toolbar.
The strange thing is, that the `ToolbarItem` on the `ShoppingCartPage` is shown twice.

**XAML from ShoppingCartPage:**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="toolbarItemFinishOrder" Activated="FinishOrder" Icon="wallet_64.png">
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <StackLayout>
```

**XAML from Page linking to ShoppingCartPage:**

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="toolbarItemShoppingCart" Activated="ShoppingCart_Clicked" Icon="shoppingCart2_64.png"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code from Page linking to ShoppingCartPage:**

```
public partial class ArticleSearchPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ArticleSearchPage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.Content = new ArticleSearchView();

            //TODO: Localization
            this.Title = "Artikel";
        }

        protected void ShoppingCart_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new ShoppingCartPage()));
        }
```

I hope that I made myself clear and that you can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to see:

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new ShoppingCartPage());
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That fixes the problem with two ToolBars, but now I can't access my MasterDetail menu. Is there a way to do this. If not, I could manage to life with this solution.

Comment: Slip your finger in the middle of the screen to see if you have master menu appearing..

Comment: If i swipe from the left screen border to the middle, the menu appears and I can live with that. I just have to explain this functionality to my customer, but I think that an additional button in the toolbar is confusing. Thx!

Comment: Normally when you have masterdetail page you can acces to menu from toolbar but if you push another page on it you have to go back to masterdetail to acces your menu (from toolbar)..